# BigTreeTech mini e3 V1.2 endstop installation

Tags: wiring, endstop, skr-mini-e3, bigtreetech

I recently purchased a BigTreeTech mini e3 V1.2 controller for my custom built 3D printer (as opposed to an pre-purchased ender 3). In doing so, I ran into the problem that the endstops I have been using have three wires: Power, Ground, and signal. The mini e3 V1.2 that I purchased uses endstop connections that only have two pins. This can be seen in the schematic below on the bottom right of the controller. I don't know where to buy endstops that only have two pins and have not been able to find anything online. If anybody knows where these can be bought or how the 3 pinned endstops are supposed to be wired up it would be much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to connect the red (+) wire of the endstops. The controller board uses a technique to ensure the signal is 3.3 V or ground, see the top left schematics of [this link](https://github.com/bigtreetech/BIGTREETECH-SKR-mini-E3/blob/master/hardware/BTT%20SKR%20MINI%20E3%20V1.2/BTT%20SKR%20mini%20E3%20V1.2sch.pdf) (will insert an image later!). Specifics about this technology is found [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pull-up_resistor) and is explained as using a pull up resistor.

What happens is that the signal is always reported as triggered, unless the endstop connects the signal wire to ground.

[This link](https://github.com/bigtreetech/BIGTREETECH-SKR-mini-E3/blob/master/hardware/BTT%20SKR%20MINI%20E3%20V1.2/BTT%20SKR%20MINI%20E3%20V1.2PIN.pdf) shows that only ground and signal are required (will insert an image later!).